# Android Studio 3.0 Development Essentials Kotlin Edition Chapter 37 - Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-seekbar

this is my first Android/Kotlin question and new to android so please have patience with me.

In this android book which is listed in the title on chapter 37 when I try to use the "seekBar" to make text bigger/smaller the app crashes. I am used to Swift/Xcode where when the app crashes the program goes right to where the crash is caused, and android doesn't do that.

Can anyone point me in the right direction to how I can customize android studio to act like Xcode? But as far as the "seekBar" here is my code below... if more files are need please ask and I will provide.

Also, if you look at the bottom of the code and see the function "override fun onStopTrackingTouch" this code isn't recommend in the book to implement in the file. If I don't implement this, there is a error in the file.

Again, please have patience with me since I am new to android and need help.

```
package com.ebookfrenzy.fragmentexample

import android.os.Bundle
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.SeekBar
import android.content.Context
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.toolbar_fragment.*


class ToolbarFragment: Fragment(), SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {

var seekvalue = 10

var activityCallback: ToolbarFragment.ToolbarListener? = null

interface ToolbarListener {
    fun onButtonClick(position: Int, text: String)
}

override fun onAttach(context: Context?) {
    super.onAttach(context)
    try {
        activityCallback = context as ToolbarListener
    } catch (e: ClassCastException) {
        throw ClassCastException(context?.toString() + " must implement ToolbarListener")
    }
}

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    val view = inflater?.inflate(R.layout.toolbar_fragment, container, false)

    val seekBar: SeekBar? = view?.findViewById(R.id.seekBar1)
    val button: Button? = view?.findViewById(R.id.button1)

    seekBar?.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this)

    button?.setOnClickListener { v: View -> buttonClicked(v) }

    return view
}

private fun buttonClicked(view: View) {
    activityCallback?.onButtonClick(seekvalue, editText1.text.toString())
}

override fun onProgressChanged(seekBar: SeekBar, progress: Int, fromUser: Boolean) {
    seekvalue = progress
}

override fun onStartTrackingTouch(arg0: SeekBar) {

}

override fun onStopTrackingTouch(arg0: SeekBar) {
    TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
}
```

**Edit Logcat output**

```
08-12 12:24:18.394 16587-16587/? E/Zygote: isWhitelistProcess - Process is Whitelisted
08-12 12:24:18.395 16587-16587/? E/libpersona: scanKnoxPersonas
08-12 12:24:18.396 16587-16587/? E/libpersona: Couldn't open the File - /data/system/users/0/personalist.xml - No such file or directory
08-12 12:24:18.400 16587-16587/? W/SELinux: SELinux selinux_android_compute_policy_index : Policy Index[2],  Con:u:r:zygote:s0 RAM:SEPF_SM-N950U_8.0.0_0009, [-1 -1 -1 -1 0 1]
08-12 12:24:18.401 16587-16587/? I/SELinux: SELinux: seapp_context_lookup: seinfo=untrusted, level=s0:c512,c768, pkgname=com.ebookfrenzy.fragmentexample 
08-12 12:24:18.417 16587-16587/? I/zygote64: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
08-12 12:24:18.452 16587-16587/? D/TimaKeyStoreProvider: TimaKeyStore is not enabled: cannot add TimaSignature Service and generateKeyPair Service
08-12 12:24:18.453 16587-16587/? D/ActivityThread: Added TimaKeyStore provider
08-12 12:24:18.501 16587-16587/com.ebookfrenzy.fragmentexample I/zygote64: no shared libraies, dex_files: 1
08-12 12:24:18.588 16587-16613/com.ebookfrenzy.fragmentexample I/vndksupport: sphal namespace is not configured for this process. Loading /vendor/lib64/egl/libEGL_adreno.so from the current namespace instead.
08-12 12:24:18.591 16587-16613/com.ebookfrenzy.fragmentexample D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib64/egl/libEGL_adreno.so
08-12 12:24:18.596 16587-16587/com.ebookfrenzy.fragmentexample I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
08-12 12:24:18.600 16587-16613/com.ebookfrenzy.fragmentexample I/vndksupport: sphal namespace is not configured for this process. Loading /vendor/lib64/egl/libGLESv1_CM_adreno.so from the current namespace instead.
08-12 12:24:18.600 16587-16613/com.ebookfrenzy.fragmentexample D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib64/egl/libGLESv1_CM_adreno.so
08-12 12:24:18.788 16587-16619/com.ebookfrenzy.fragmentexample D/OpenGLRenderer: HWUI GL Pipeline
08-12 12:24:18.807 16587-16587/com.ebookfrenzy.fragmentexample D/ViewRootImpl@9c84bd9[FragmentExampleActivity]: setView = DecorView@43a999e[FragmentExampleActivity] TM=true MM=false
08-12 12:24:18.829 16587-16587/com.ebookfrenzy.fragmentexample D/ViewRootImpl@9c84bd9[FragmentExampleActivity]: dispatchAttachedToWindow
08-12 12:24:18.836 16587-16613/com.ebookfrenzy.fragmentexample I/vndksupport: sphal namespace is not configured for this process. Loading /vendor/lib64/egl/libGLESv2_adreno.so from the current namespace instead.
08-12 12:24:18.842 16587-16613/com.ebookfrenzy.fragmentexample D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib64/egl/libGLESv2_adreno.so
08-12 12:24:18.862 16587-16587/com.ebookfrenzy.fragmentexample D/ViewRootImpl@9c84bd9[FragmentExampleActivity]: Relayout returned: old=[0,0][0,0] new=[0,0][1440,2960] result=0x7 surface={valid=true 542086074368} changed=true
08-12 12:24:18.862 16587-16619/com.ebookfrenzy.fragmentexample I/Adreno: QUALCOMM build                   : 7780dff, Iaaa4d6d123
    Build Date                       : 01/17/18
    OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: EV031.22.00.01
    Local Branch                     : 
    Remote Branch                    : refs/tags/AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.UM.6.4.R1.08.00.00.309.049
    Remote Branch                    : NONE
    Reconstruct Branch               : NOTHING
08-12 12:24:18.868 16587-16619/com.ebookfrenzy.fragmentexample I/vndksupport: sphal namespace is not configured for this process. Loading /vendor/lib64/hw/gralloc.msm8998.so from the current namespace instead.
08-12 12:24:18.884 16587-16619/com.ebookfrenzy.fragmentexample I/Adreno: PFP: 0x005ff087, ME: 0x005ff063
08-12 12:24:18.891 16587-16619/com.ebookfrenzy.fragmentexample I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
08-12 12:24:18.891 16587-16619/com.ebookfrenzy.fragmentexample D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 2
08-12 12:24:18.897 16587-16619/com.ebookfrenzy.fragmentexample D/libGLESv1: STS_GLApi : DTS, ODTC are not allowed for Package : com.ebookfrenzy.fragmentexample
08-12 12:24:18.899 16587-16619/com.ebookfrenzy.fragmentexample D/OpenGLRenderer: eglCreateWindowSurface = 0x7e2b725030
08-12 12:24:18.912 16587-16619/com.ebookfrenzy.fragmentexample D/OpenGLRenderer: eglDestroySurface = 0x7e2b725030
08-12 12:24:18.923 16587-16587/com.ebookfrenzy.fragmentexample D/ViewRootImpl@9c84bd9[FragmentExampleActivity]: Relayout returned: old=[0,0][1440,2960] new=[0,0][1440,2960] result=0x5 surface={valid=false 0} changed=true
08-12 12:24:21.055 16587-16587/com.ebookfrenzy.fragmentexample W/zygote64: Current dex file has more than one class in it. Calling RetransformClasses on this class might fail if no transformations are applied to it!
08-12 12:24:29.651 16587-16587/com.ebookfrenzy.fragmentexample D/ViewRootImpl@9c84bd9[FragmentExampleActivity]: Relayout returned: old=[0,0][1440,2960] new=[0,0][1440,2960] result=0x7 surface={valid=true 542086074368} changed=true
08-12 12:24:29.668 16587-16619/com.ebookfrenzy.fragmentexample D/OpenGLRenderer: eglCreateWindowSurface = 0x7e2b725030
08-12 12:24:29.680 16587-16587/com.ebookfrenzy.fragmentexample D/ViewRootImpl@9c84bd9[FragmentExampleActivity]: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: frame=Rect(0, 0 - 1440, 2960) ci=Rect(0, 84 - 0, 168) vi=Rect(0, 84 - 0, 168) or=1
08-12 12:24:29.702 16587-16619/com.ebookfrenzy.fragmentexample I/vndksupport: sphal namespace is not configured for this process. Loading /vendor/lib64/hw/gralloc.msm8998.so from the current namespace instead.
08-12 12:24:29.706 16587-16779/com.ebookfrenzy.fragmentexample E/StudioProfiler: JVMTI error: 15(JVMTI_ERROR_THREAD_NOT_ALIVE) 
08-12 12:24:29.706 16587-16779/com.ebookfrenzy.fragmentexample I/chatty: uid=10229(u0_a229) hwuiTask1 identical 2 lines
08-12 12:24:29.706 16587-16779/com.ebookfrenzy.fragmentexample E/StudioProfiler: JVMTI error: 15(JVMTI_ERROR_THREAD_NOT_ALIVE) 
08-12 12:24:29.706 16587-16780/com.ebookfrenzy.fragmentexample E/StudioProfiler: JVMTI error: 15(JVMTI_ERROR_THREAD_NOT_ALIVE) 
    JVMTI error: 15(JVMTI_ERROR_THREAD_NOT_ALIVE) 
08-12 12:24:29.706 16587-16779/com.ebookfrenzy.fragmentexample E/StudioProfiler: JVMTI error: 15(JVMTI_ERROR_THREAD_NOT_ALIVE) 
08-12 12:24:29.706 16587-16780/com.ebookfrenzy.fragmentexample E/StudioProfiler: JVMTI error: 15(JVMTI_ERROR_THREAD_NOT_ALIVE) 
08-12 12:24:29.788 16587-16587/com.ebookfrenzy.fragmentexample D/ViewRootImpl@9c84bd9[FragmentExampleActivity]: MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 1
08-12 12:24:29.809 16587-16587/com.ebookfrenzy.fragmentexample I/InputMethodManager: startInputInner - mService.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus
08-12 12:24:29.836 16587-16587/com.ebookfrenzy.fragmentexample I/AssistStructure: Flattened final assist data: 2060 bytes, containing 1 windows, 7 views
08-12 12:24:36.825 16587-16592/com.ebookfrenzy.fragmentexample I/zygote64: Do partial code cache collection, code=29KB, data=27KB
08-12 12:24:36.826 16587-16592/com.ebookfrenzy.fragmentexample I/zygote64: After code cache collection, code=29KB, data=27KB
    Increasing code cache capacity to 128KB
08-12 12:24:37.041 16587-16587/com.ebookfrenzy.fragmentexample D/ViewRootImpl@9c84bd9[FragmentExampleActivity]: ViewPostIme pointer 0
08-12 12:24:37.115 16587-16587/com.ebookfrenzy.fragmentexample D/ViewRootImpl@9c84bd9[FragmentExampleActivity]: ViewPostIme pointer 1
08-12 12:24:37.125 16587-16587/com.ebookfrenzy.fragmentexample D/InputMethodManager: SSI - flag : 0 Pid : 16587 view : com.ebookfrenzy.fragmentexample
08-12 12:24:37.203 16587-16587/com.ebookfrenzy.fragmentexample D/ViewRootImpl@9c84bd9[FragmentExampleActivity]: MSG_RESIZED: frame=Rect(0, 0 - 1440, 2960) ci=Rect(0, 84 - 0, 168) vi=Rect(0, 84 - 0, 1253) or=1
08-12 12:24:38.620 16587-16592/com.ebookfrenzy.fragmentexample I/zygote64: Do partial code cache collection, code=60KB, data=48KB
    After code cache collection, code=60KB, data=48KB
    Increasing code cache capacity to 256KB
08-12 12:24:41.591 16587-16587/com.ebookfrenzy.fragmentexample D/ViewRootImpl@9c84bd9[FragmentExampleActivity]: ViewPostIme pointer 0
08-12 12:24:41.675 16587-16587/com.ebookfrenzy.fragmentexample D/ViewRootImpl@9c84bd9[FragmentExampleActivity]: ViewPostIme pointer 1
08-12 12:24:43.420 16587-16592/com.ebookfrenzy.fragmentexample I/zygote64: Compiler allocated 8MB to compile void android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals()
08-12 12:24:43.791 16587-16587/com.ebookfrenzy.fragmentexample D/ViewRootImpl@9c84bd9[FragmentExampleActivity]: ViewPostIme pointer 0
08-12 12:24:44.227 16587-16592/com.ebookfrenzy.fragmentexample I/zygote64: Do full code cache collection, code=122KB, data=100KB
    After code cache collection, code=105KB, data=70KB
08-12 12:24:44.261 16587-16587/com.ebookfrenzy.fragmentexample D/ViewRootImpl@9c84bd9[FragmentExampleActivity]: ViewPostIme pointer 1
08-12 12:24:44.263 16587-16587/com.ebookfrenzy.fragmentexample E/InputEventReceiver: Exception dispatching input event.
08-12 12:24:44.263 16587-16587/com.ebookfrenzy.fragmentexample E/MessageQueue-JNI: Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
08-12 12:24:44.282 16587-16587/com.ebookfrenzy.fragmentexample E/MessageQueue-JNI: kotlin.NotImplementedError: An operation is not implemented: not implemented
        at com.ebookfrenzy.fragmentexample.ToolbarFragment.onStopTrackingTouch(ToolbarFragment.kt:61)
        at android.widget.SeekBar.onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar.java:123)
        at android.widget.AbsSeekBar.onTouchEvent(AbsSeekBar.java:1289)
        at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:12539)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3159)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2844)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3159)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2844)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3159)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2844)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3159)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2844)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3159)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2844)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:600)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1871)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:3384)
        at com.android.tools.profiler.support.event.WindowProfilerCallback.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowProfilerCallback.java:69)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:562)
        at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:12787)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5625)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:5420)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4913)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4966)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4932)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:5069)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4940)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:5126)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4913)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4966)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4932)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4940)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4913)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7672)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:7612)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7573)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7783)
        at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:197)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:325)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:142)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6940)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
08-12 12:24:44.282 16587-16587/com.ebookfrenzy.fragmentexample D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
08-12 12:24:44.289 16587-16587/com.ebookfrenzy.fragmentexample E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.ebookfrenzy.fragmentexample, PID: 16587
    kotlin.NotImplementedError: An operation is not implemented: not implemented
        at com.ebookfrenzy.fragmentexample.ToolbarFragment.onStopTrackingTouch(ToolbarFragment.kt:61)
        at android.widget.SeekBar.onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar.java:123)
        at android.widget.AbsSeekBar.onTouchEvent(AbsSeekBar.java:1289)
        at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:12539)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3159)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2844)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3159)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2844)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3159)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2844)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3159)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2844)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3159)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2844)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:600)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1871)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:3384)
        at com.android.tools.profiler.support.event.WindowProfilerCallback.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowProfilerCallback.java:69)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:562)
        at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:12787)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5625)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:5420)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4913)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4966)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4932)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:5069)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4940)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:5126)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4913)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4966)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4932)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4940)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4913)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7672)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:7612)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7573)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7783)
        at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:197)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:325)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:142)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6940)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```

Comment: In Android Studio when the app crashes you can open the Logcat and see where the app crashed. So copy the segment that indicates the error and paste it here.

Comment: Android's log is called "logcat". Look for a window at the bottom of the screen. In that window you should see (in red) a "stack trace" of the crash somewhere (near the bottom of the log). Then you can click on each line and Studio will take you there.

Comment: I just added the logcat, sorry it's not shifted over 4 spaces

Comment: Dont understand negative vote. Im asking for help and patience because I am new

Comment: if someone can explain what to look for in the logcat that would be amazing. Sorry I am a noob for android :/

Comment: Do you get this error although you added `onStopTrackingTouch`  and `onStartTrackingTouch`?

Comment: mTak yes I did get this error even though I implemented both

Comment: @LukasBimba see my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just implement all 3 methods:

```
override fun onProgressChanged(seekBar: SeekBar, progress: Int, fromUser: Boolean) {
    seekvalue = progress
}

override fun onStartTrackingTouch(arg0: SeekBar) {
    seekvalue = arg0.progress
}

override fun onStopTrackingTouch(arg0: SeekBar) {
    seekvalue = arg0.progress
}
```

or  
replace `arg0: SeekBar` with `arg0: SeekBar?` in the header of the last 2 methods.

Comment: Thank you! Since I am a beginner I am going to get errors on simple things and not know how to fix it lol. Thank you again for you time and patience